# How to support Image Resize Feature in Vaadin 8 Rich Text Area Component?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

How to support Image Resize Feature in Vaadin 8 Rich Text Area Component?

when we copy/paste image from Ms Word/Excel to Rich Text Area, Image resize feature not present.

..Also copy Table from Excel File to Rich Text Area copies only content
Table structure/fonts headers will be lost

Comment: I don't think Rich Text Area is even trying to be 100% compatible with Word or Excel features. For example, having table structure copy-pasted in text is not something I'd expect to work out of the box. You might want to look into add-ons or a custom JavaScript widget for that kind of feature.

Comment: I was looking for https://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/#richeditor .. can we customize existing Vaadin 8 Rich Text Area which is based on GWT like above?